# How to open a program as another user inside a logged display?

Tags: ubuntu, users, non-root-user, kubuntu, display

I'm trying to open netbeans as a different user, but isn't working.
I'm running a Kubuntu 12.04 LTS with KDE.

And I tried the following:
Open a terminal, type `su - myotheruser`, type the myotheruser password.
Then tried to open netbeans: `/opt/netbeans/7.3/bin/netbeans` (netbeans is installed on */opt/netbeans/7.3*).

I got the following:

```
Erro: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I tried some commands like `export DISPLAY=":0.0"`, `xhost +`, `xhost +local:all` and other commands related [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-0-0-as-the-value-of-the-display-variable-178234/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t). None worked.

Is important to me that *myother* user not be in the sudoers file.

If I end the session with *mycurrentuser* and logon with the *myotheruser*  I can easily open netbeans.

I need open netbeans as `myotheruser` because I would like to work on a project that belongs to this user and just to it. If I changes permissions, looks like when I versionnig the project the user will loose the exclusivity.

So, how can I solve this? How can I open netbeans as a different user inside of another user display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always try the following:

```
ssh -Y otheruser@localhost "/opt/netbeans/7.3/bin/netbeans"
```

:)

Comment: Thx a lot, works @tink.

Answer (score 0):

I use `gksu`:

```
gksu -u myotheruser /opt/netbeans/7.3/bin/netbeans
```

Maybe try also `kdesu`.